# Why does my symlink to /usr/local/bin not work?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link, julia-lang

I installed Julia locally by unpacking it into a folder. Then I tried to add the executable to `/usr/local/bin` since I don't want to modify the `$PATH`.

```
sudo ln -s bin/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

If I now execute Julia in a new shell window the following message pops up:

```
$ julia
zsh: command not found: julia

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/
total 12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jan  1 10:08 julia -> bin/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia
```

So obviously the symlink exists nevertheless my shell tells me the command was not found. What is the problem here?

Comment: The symlink does indeed exist, but the question is, does the file that it points to exist? I.e. are you 100% sure that there *actually* exists an executable file at `/usr/local/bin/bin/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia`?

Comment: There is information missing I guess. I executed this in my home folder so the folder is at $HOME/bin/julia. Executing this command with the working directory in home leads to the described error. I used bash completetion for the paths so I am 100% sure they were correct when I called ln.

Answer (score 16):

The solution is rather simple. Use an **absolute symlink** here such that the first argument of `ln -s` is a full path instead.

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/bin/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

Now it **opens correctly and executes as expected.**

The second and more complex solution is to use a **relative symlink**. However it has to be relative to the folder where the symlink will be created. Thus starting at `/usr/local/bin` one has to move up three folders to be at `/` and then descend into the appropriate folder.

```
sudo ln -s ../../../home/user/bin/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

**Update:** The comment below is correct and I edited the answer accordingly. Relative symlinks are fine and exist for good reasons however here they don't make any sense since they complicate the path a lot.

Comment: It doesn't *always* have to be absolute, it's just the reasonable thing to do in this case. Relative symlinks have their uses, or they wouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: Good comment! I just now tried to understand how a solution with a relative symlink would look like and upated the answer.